# Scala - Multiple inheritance with App trait

Tags: scala, multiple-inheritance

Consider two traits, TestTrait1 and TestTrait and assume NewObject extends both.
The idea is to make use of variable in TestTrait1 in TestTrait. The below code works perfectly fine.

```
scala> trait TestTrait1 {
 | val arguments1: Array[String] = Array("1","2")
 | }

defined trait TestTrait1

scala> trait TestTrait {
 | val arguments: Array[String]
 | val len = arguments.length
 | }

defined trait TestTrait

scala> object NewObject extends TestTrait1 with TestTrait {
 |  lazy val arguments = arguments1
 | }

defined object NewObject

scala> NewObject
res30: NewObject.type = NewObject$@7c013560
```

Now replace TestTrait1 with App. Since arguments is set for lazy evaluation, I will assume that even in case of DelayedInit, the below code will work.

```
scala> object NewObject extends App with TestTrait {
 | lazy val arguments = args
 | }
```

But it doesn't. What is the reason behind this?

```
scala> NewObject
java.lang.NullPointerException
at TestTrait$class.$init$(<console>:12)
... 35 elided
```

If this is the case, what is the solution to use args in another trait similar to TestTrait here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
trait TestTrait1 {
  val arguments1: Array[String] = Array("1","2")
}

trait TestTrait {
  val arguments: Array[String]
  val len = arguments.length
}
```

If you see the difference, the TestTrait has a member `len` that would eagerly get initialized. But `args` is a `def` inside `App` which happens to have a default value as `null`. If you change the `len` to `lazy val` or `def` it would not blow-up with NPE.

Let's try this on a quick REPL session:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait TestTrait {
  def arguments: Array[String]
  lazy val len = arguments.length
}

object NewObject extends App with TestTrait {
  override lazy val arguments = super.args // Added `override` and `super` just for clarity.
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait TestTrait
defined object NewObject

scala> NewObject
res0: NewObject.type = NewObject$@5ace1ed4

scala> NewObject.arguments
res1: Array[String] = null
```

If you want to reproduce the issue you can call `len` as below:

```
scala> NewObject.len
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at TestTrait$class.len(<console>:12)
  at NewObject$.len$lzycompute(<console>:15)
  at NewObject$.len(<console>:15)
  ... 33 elided
```

So, the answer to your question is you would need to make `len` either `lazy val` or `def` if you want to invoke the instance of `NewObject`. I would suggest making the NewObject a `class` or `trait` because you do not want an unsafe/eagerly initialized `len` member that would blow-up with NPE.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this with the same example. The explanation makes perfect sense.